# Is there a way to test android app actions without using the test tool

Tags: android, app-actions

I'm currently trying to send my app to a group of testers and i want to know if there is a way they can test the app actions without having access to the project nor the test tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options: Share the adb commands that App Actions Test Tool (AATT) generates or use Google Assistant. You still require to create a preview for the Google accounts testing App Actions.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking for is some [App Distribution](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution). You will have to register your applications with Firebase, but this will allow you to send specific versions of your app to testers. This is very similar to TestFlight on iOS. This does require that you generate an APK file and upload to the Firebase account.